# How can I automatically show a jquery colorbox on my page when a certain $_GET variable is passed?

Tags: php, jquery, query-string, colorbox

I have a jquery colorbox (lightbox) that pops up when users click a button on my page. Under certain conditions though i want this colorbox to appear without the user having to click a button. For example when the page is loaded and variable is passed in the query string I want to pop up the colorbox.

For example the following code shows how when user clicks the signup button the colorbox appears (this is for a page called example.php)

```
<p class="signup_button"><a href="#" class="free_signup_link"><img src="images/buttons/sign_up_now.gif" alt="Sign Up Now"></a></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.free_signup_link').colorbox({href:"signup.php?type=5"});
</script>
```

What I want to do is if the page is loaded with a variable in the query string then the colorbox is automatically shown (eg for example.php?show=1)

```
if($_GET['show'] == "1") {
// show the color box 
}
```

Anyone know how to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

This should work, it's probably considered a bit "dirty" however.

```
<?php
if($_GET['show'] == "1") { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.colorbox({href:"signup.php?type=5"});
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use jQuery?

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}

var show = getUrlVars()["show"];

if(show == 1) {
    $.colorbox({href:"signup.php?type=5"}).click();
}
```

Reference: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
if($_GET['show'] == "1") {
    echo '
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.colorbox( ... ); // or whatever that triggers the colorbox
        </script>
    ';
}
```